# Register & Deploy Form Recognizer generated model with AKS

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I have create a model using  Microsoft Sample labelling tool (Form Recognizer) and wanted to register and deploy the model in AKS but could not find the steps as how it can be accomplished.

Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy the model to AKS.
Since you already trained the model, you just need to connect straight to the same Cognitive Services you were using to train it.
You can do so by using the [REST API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1-preview-3/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm) or an [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=preview%2Cv2-1).

Find more information on [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/?branch=release-build-cogserv-forms-recognizer).

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a form recognizer container to AKS. You will need to be registered for the form recognizer container preview. There are [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/containers/form-recognizer-container-install-run?tabs=layout) here to take you through deploying Form Recognizer on docker.

Once you are familiar with the container for form recognizer you can deploy it to an AKS node cluster of your choice. There is a [full tutorial on how to do this with the Azure Vision service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/deploy-computer-vision-on-premises), you will need to swap the target image for the form recognizer ones.

Once deployed in AKS you can then train a custom model on that instance.

Comment: This is a useful tool for converting the docker-compose.yaml(s) provided into AKS deployment yamls: (https://kompose.io/)